# Open submenu on click, jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I want that if we click on a list which has children, children ul (submenus) to show up. Standard menu - submenu system that we see around. I tried a code which is not working. Probably you have better idea ?

http://jsfiddle.net/JeremyCh/BjTYY/2/

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="/accueil/">Accueil</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="/disciplines/">Disciplines</a>
      <ul class='children'>
        <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="/disciplines/galerie/">Galerie</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-21"><a href="/disciplines/definitions/">Définitions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="/professeurs/">Professeurs</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="/planning/">Planning</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="/tarifs/">Tarifs</a>
      <ul class='children'>
        <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="/tarifs/cours/">Cours</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a href="/tarifs/location/">Location</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu').find('> li').click(function() {
        jQuery('.menu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
        jQuery(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    }); 
})
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean, in context? What did you expect it to do that it didn't do, what did it do that you didn't want it to do, what errors did it generate?

Comment: Good question David. I want submenus to open up, when I click parent items. I was actually looking for a standard menu / submenu system where submenus stay hidden on page load, and shows up when we click the parent list item.

Comment: @Jeremy - you should move the above comment to the question since it is part of the question not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go..

u assigned class `.menu` to wrong element,assign it to the main ul, now u can style accordingly..

**html**

```
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8 current_page_item"><a href="#">Disciplines</a>
  <ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="/disciplines/galerie/">Galerie</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-21"><a href="/disciplines/definitions/">Définitions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="/professeurs/">Professeurs</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="/planning/">Planning</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="/tarifs/">Tarifs</a>
  <ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="/tarifs/cours/">Cours</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a href="/tarifs/location/">Location</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
```

**js**

```
$('.menu').find('> li').click(function() {
$('.menu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
$(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhar, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try  changing your selectors in your JQuery from `jQuery('.menu').find('> li')` and `jQuery('.menu > li')` to `jQuery('.menu').find('> ul > li')` and `jQuery('.menu > ul > li')`.

From what I know the `>` selector selects on Direct child descendants, ie, in this case the ul, and hence the li's are not Direct child descendants of the div.menu element.